# calling another python and capturing the output in variables

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an existing python script with command params that outputs a string like below . I am trying to call this into another python script and pass the prodName dynamically through another variable.

I tried something like this which works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.call("/usr/st/getProdID.py ProdName=someProd_name Prod_config=/usr/st/prod/prod_id.txt", shell=True)
```

output:

```
Ad897
```

I could not redirect this output to a variable

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

pid = subprocess.call("/usr/st/getProdID.py ProdName=someProd_name Prod_config=/usr/st/prod/prod_id.txt", shell=True)
print "pid = ", pid
```

output:

```
Ad897

Pid = 0
```

Any help is appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: As an aside, python 2.x is end-of-life. Consider using python 3. The answer is a bit different between 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Why dont you just `import` getProdID and use it?

Comment: `check_output` and `Popen` followed by `communicate` are the two most common ways of capturing output. There are examples in the subprocess documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Python3 you could run:

```
p = subprocess.run(["getProdID.py", f"ProdName={prod}", "Prod_config=/usr/st/prod/prod_id.txt"], capture_output=True)
output = p.stdout
```

On Python2 things are litter trickier:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["getProdID.py", "ProdName={0}".format(prod), "Prod_config=/usr/st/prod/prod_id.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.stdout.read()
```

Comment: You may need to decode that p.stdout. I don't think you need a note about importing. There are many reasons to call instead of import - number 1, its written as a script that takes arguments and is not in your PYTHONPATH so likely isn't an importable module at all. Calling scripts and parsing output is a normal design.

Comment: @thecohenman i tried this but it says 

>TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output' 

however i tried this and this works better:

`p = subprocess.check_output(["getProdID.py", f"ProdName={prod}", "Prod_config=/usr/st/prod/prod_id.txt"])`
`print ("pid =", p)`

> pid =  b'Ad897\n'

Comment: maybe you are using python2. edited the answer

Comment: actually, subprocess.check_output, calls subprocess.Popen(stdout=PIPE)